# BehaviorSubject on refresh on a radio question to retain value

Tags: javascript, angular, radio-button, behaviorsubject

I am using Angular 7. I am doing a form where it uses a radio question to ask if it happened in a particular country. However, when the user goes forward and then returns, I would like the value to be retained

```
questions.service.ts
```

In this file I have the following:

```
export class QuestionsService {

inUK$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);

getQuestions(): QuestionBase<any>[] {
const questions = [
  new RadioQuestion({
    key: COUNTRY,
    label: 'Did it happen in the UK',
    options: [
      {key: true, value: 'Yes'},
      {key: false, value: 'No'},
    ],
    type: 'other',        
    value: this.inUK$.value
  }),
}    
  setIsInUK$() {
    this.inUK$.next(true);
  }
  setIsNotInUK$() {
    this.inUK$.next(false);
  }  
}
```

How to keep BehaviorSubject values. I have tried asObservables.

Other files as follows:

```
question-base.model.ts

import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';

export class QuestionBase<T> {
  value: T;
  key: string;
  label: string;
  controlType: string;
  type: string;


  constructor(options: {
    value?: T,
    key?: string,
    label?: string,
    type?: string,
  } = {}) {
    this.value = options.value;
    this.key = options.key;
    this.label = options.label;
    this.type = options.type || 'other';
  }
}

radio-question.model.ts

export class RadioQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {

  controlType = 'radio';
  options: {key: string, value: string}[] = [];

  constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super(options);
    this.options = options['options'] || [];
  }
}
```

Comment: So is the behaviourSubject working?

Comment: Yes @MikeOne, there are more questions as they are text inputs and they work fine (if I turn back the answers persist). It is just the radio questions that are not presisting when refresh or go back.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of

```
value: this.inUK$.value
```

what returns a value when a Radio Question is returned

```
value$: this.inUK$
```

and in HTML pipe it with async

```
value$ | async
```

Comment: let me know if this is what you were looking for